# Nested classes in CSS use other style from less nested style

Tags: html, css

I'm using css where is defined such style

```
.main> .test{
 display: block;
 background:#FFFFFF
}
```

This style is stored in the file which I do not want to change. My new html structure is

```
<div class="main">
  <form>
    <div class="test">
    ...
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In this case style will not be applied. My question is: Is it possible to define such css if is

```
.main> form> .test{      
 }
```

use styling like it is defined in ".main> .test" without copy paste content of such style

Comment: Unfortunately, no it is not possible.

Comment: Why copy paste, can't you use css directly on class? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=nSjaGVoscw

Comment: Using css selector without `>` is not a variant? `.main .test` will be applied to all `test` elements inside `main`, not only direct child.

Comment: `.main> .test, .main> form> .test`? To be honest I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not the author of this style: ".main> .test" and I can't/won't to change file with this style. But I want to use it in .main> form> .test.

Comment: is it ok https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/ya2aynd9/1/

Comment: @cin then add your own css rule.

Comment: @Julia yeah I know but is it possible to do it like this
     .main> form> .test{      
       use style from .main> .test{
      }

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski then it will direct apply css to that div but not to child div of .main

Comment: use this  .main >* .test{color:red; }

Comment: Probably there is the way to parse css with javascript and add the needed style to selector but i don't think it worth that. Adding custom css rule is the best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple Answer

Using plain CSS you **can't** extend a class or use inheritance between classes

-

## Possible Solution

You can do that using a CSS pre-processor like Sass, using the `@extend` keyword.

Code example:

```
.message {
  padding: .5em;
}

.message-error {
  @extend .message;
}
```

More info about its usage [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: It's almost this what I'm looking for but its not working with nested selectors. But Thank you